# Can't run jar file of JavaFx application

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I created JavaFx application. It works correct. But when I created jar file, it doesn't open. I do not get any errors logs. I use OpenJDK 17.

I tried to create a bat file:

```
java -jar Rating.jar
```

And it doesn't work. Then I tried to run application from command line and I got this error:

```
javafx runtime components are missing and are required to run this application
```

Then I added VM option:

```
--module-path "C:\Users\Admin\.jdks\openjdk-17\lib" --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

It doesn't work even from idea.

Comment: JavaFX is not part of JDK 17. You need to point your module path to the modules of your *JavaFX* jmods.

Answer (score 1):

Download the SDK for JavaFx here:

- https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

For my example, the SDK is at:

```
C:\eclipse\jdks\javafx-sdk-19\lib
```

Then use the following where `JavaFxTest.jar` is obviously your jar...

```
java --module-path "C:\eclipse\jdks\javafx-sdk-19\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar JavaFxTest.jar
```

Comment: Note that this requires a suitable `Main-Class` attribute in the JAR's manifest.